# How do I maintain the space between first name and last name in this list of strings?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of the following type that consists of the full name and location of a person.
When I print(l[0]) I expected the output to be `Spoorthy Bhat` instead of `SpoorthyBhat`
What do I do to get the expected output?

```
l = [' Spoorthy'  'Bhat', 'United States of America']
>>print(l[0])
SpoorthyBhat
```

What I tried:
I initially had a list that looked like this -
`[' Spoorthy', 'Bhat', 'United States of America']`
I wanted the First name and Last name to be a single list item and wanted to see if simply removing the first comma in the list would be enough.

To do this I used: `

```
usable = [' Spoorthy', 'Bhat', 'United States of America'] 
>> x = re.sub(",", " ", str(usable), 1)
[' Spoorthy'  'Bhat', 'United States of America']
```

But on retrieving x[0] I got `SpoorthyBhat` which is not desirable so I tried using

`x = re.sub(",", "\s", str(usable), 1)`

to see if I could replace the comma with an empty space in this way but this gives an error.

What do I do to ensure that the first name and last name have a space between them?

I understand that I am not using good coding methods here but I am just beginning to learn how to work around things.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Several consecutive string literals will be evaluated as one string literal. If you want a space, you need to put a space into the string: `'Spoorthy Bhat'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were on the right track with your first implementation where you had the first name, last name, and country as three separate list elements.  If you stick with that approach you can get the output you want using string formatting like this:

```
first, last, country = [' Spoorthy', 'Bhat', 'United States of America']
print(f"{first} {last}, {country}")
```

```
Spoorthy Bhat, United States of America
```

Comment: usable1 = [usable[0]+ " "+ usable[1], usable[-1]]  also gave me the desired output without using regex, thanks a lot for your answer